# I need to make a search with private attribute in C++ objects

Tags: c++, oop, search, compare

So I'm currently working on a project with no database, managing the archives manually and I have a problem, I need to search the archive using a private attribute from my class, that being the NOME attribute,I know how to do it using a non-private attribute though, here's the structure of the class

```
class REGISTRO{
    private :
        char NOME[40];
        int DN, MN, AN, DA, MA, AA;
    public :
        int ID;
        bool status;
        void setNOME(char ENTRAFUN[40])
        {
            strcpy(NOME, ENTRAFUN);
        }
        void setDATA(int DIA, int MES, int ANO)
        {
            DN = DIA;
            MN = MES;
            AN = ANO;
        }
        void getNOME(void)
        {
            cout << NOME;
        }
};
```

I don't know much about object oriented programming, but how can I compare the NOME private attribute with other variable?

Comment: Can you modify `REGISTRO`? If so you can make the comparator a public member or static function. Second option is to make a friend function.

Comment: @super Yeah, I can definetly modify the class. I'll try the comparator function idea thanks.

Comment: Note: in C++ they're called members or variables, never attributes. A `class` has data and function members.

Comment: @Paul Evans Yeah, I preffer to use the term members or fields, but most people stick to the usual Java terms.

Comment: The `getNOME` is odd. Based on the name I'd expect it to return a `const char *` pointing to the `NOME` member variable. returning nothing and printing "NOME" strikes me as of limited use.

Comment: @user4581301 Noted, thanks for the advice.